# session_destroy in codeigniter don't work for IE

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

session_destroy in codeigniter don't work for IE

when I make logout I destroy the session, but when I enter to the page where I must be logged, its enter as if its were logged, that happens only in IE, how can this be fixed?

Comment: It might be good to check that this isn't IE's famous cache being funny?

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be your IE being funny. Clear all your IE cache and restart the browser. Try visiting the page with private browsing ON

Comment: but how can this be fixed in the code?, the user will not do that

Comment: Did it work? It is your browser not the code :). Have you tested this on several different machines, or it is just your ?

Comment: the problem is that, codeigniter doesn't use the standart $_SESSION, it uses his own sessions, i think here is the problem